# undefined method, rails 4.1.9, rspec 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following module:

```
module BlackBird
  module PublishToSites
    module User

      @site = nil

      @params = nil

      @times = 5

      def self.publish_user(params, request_url)
        if Site.all != nil
          threads = []
          Site.all.each do |s|
            @site = s
            @params = params
            threads << Thread.new do
              responses = rescue_500(5) { publish(s, params) }
              deal_with_response(s, responses, request_url)
            end
          end

          return threads
        else
          # Send Email
          #  - Use No Sites Template
        end
      end

      private

      def self.publish(site, params)
        response = Typhoeus.post(
        site.site_api_url + 'users',
        :body => params.to_json,
        :headers => {
            "Authorization" => "Token token=\"#{site.site_api_key}\"",
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
          }
        )
        return response
      end

      def self.rescue_500(n , &block)
        responses = []
        (n-1).times {
          response = block.call
          if response.code == 500
            responses << response
            sleep 15
          else
            responses << response
            return responses.uniq(&:code)
          end
        }

        responses << block.call
        return responses.uniq(&:code)
      end

      def deal_with_response(site, responses, request_url)
        response.each do |response|
          if response.code == 200
            send_request(site.site_api_url, site.site_api_key, response, request_url)
          elsif response.code == 404
            send_request(site.site_api_url, site.site_api_key, response, request_url)
            GeneralMailer.recieved_404(ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_NAME'], ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_EMAIL'], site, response).deliver_now
          elsif response.code == 500
            send_request(site.site_api_url, site.site_api_key, response, request_url)
            GeneralMailer.recieved_500(ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_NAME'], ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_EMAIL'], site, response).deliver_now
          else
            send_request(site.site_api_url, site.site_api_key, response, request_url)
            GeneralMailer.recieved_error(ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_NAME'], ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_EMAIL'], site, response).deliver_now
          end
        end
      end

      def send_request(site, api_key, response, from_site)
        # do something here.
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It contains the following method, under `private` called `deal_with_response(site, responses, request_url)`

The fact that its "private" is not causing this error because I have other tests that test the `rescue_500` method.

The following test:

```
it "should send no email (200)" do
  response = double("response", :code => 200)
  site = double("site", :site_api_url => 'http://google.ca', site_api_key: 'sdsadsasada')
  send_request_method = double()
  send_request_method.stub(:send_request).with(site.site_api_url, site.site_api_key, [response], 'http://google.ca').and_return nil

  expect{ BlackBird::PublishToSites::User.deal_with_response(site.site_api_url, response, 'http://google.ca') }.to_not change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }
end
```

Fails due to the fact that:

```
1) BlackBird::PublishToSites::User Test that emails are being sent should send no email (200)
     Failure/Error: expect{ BlackBird::PublishToSites::User.deal_with_response(site.site_api_url, response, 'http://google.ca') }.to_not change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `deal_with_response' for BlackBird::PublishToSites::User:Module
     # ./spec/blackbird/publish_to_sites/user_spec.rb:129:in `(root)'
     # ./spec/blackbird/publish_to_sites/user_spec.rb:129:in `(root)'
```

Line 129 in this case is:

```
expect{ BlackBird::PublishToSites::User.deal_with_response(site.site_api_url, response, 'http://google.ca') }.to_not change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }
```

How is: `deal_with_response` undefined for this module? Am I missing something? a typo? I looked it over 5 times, I am calling the right method ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your other methods in the module are defined as module methods (with `def self.method_name`), and are thus callable on the module itself without an encapsulating object. The `deal_with_response` method is not defined in this way, and is therefore an instance method which is only callable as an instance method on a class when the module is included.

[Source.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html)